# How do I localize man pages for chinese?

Tags: man, locale, documentation

Doing the prerequisite google search didn't turn up anything: I'm looking for a way to install and use localized chinese versions of the man pages (assuming there is some localized package somewhere).

1. Is there a localized package to install? Better yet, is it already installed in the default install?
2. How do I activate this? Do I just change my locale? Is there a canonical way to change the locale outside of just resetting the environment variable in my rc file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about the first question but here there is a localized package called [manpages-zh](https://github.com/lidaobing/manpages-zh). This can be installed via `aptitude`. Instructions for activation/installation are [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/chengmo/archive/2010/10/27/1862553.html). They're in Chinese but you can guess from the command line screenshots what you need to do.

---

I actually installed it and here's the process:

1. `aptitude install language-pack-zh-hans` If you are running Ubuntu Server (like me), you'll pull in a bunch of unnecessary GUI packages. I'm not sure how to get *just* the chinese locale data. I searched `aptitude` with 'zh' and 'locale' and the thing that made the most sense was this package.
2. `aptitude install manpages-zh`
3. `export LANG=zh_CN.utf8`. This is different from what the activation/installation instructions are, but they are a bit dated.
4. `man man` should show this in chinese. Obviously not all the man pages are Chinese but hopefully it will help your Chinese colleagues more than not.